# sqlite3_open returning error code 23 that's SQLITE_AUTH

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sqlite

When I am opening my sqlite database using sqlite_open function its working fine in foreground  mode but when the iOS device is in sleep mode then it returning the error code 23. I searched for that error code on google then I found that it is 'SQLITE_AUTH'. I also got the error message that 'authorization denied'. Can someone explain me about this why it is happening and what is this error stands for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot about it but I didn't found anything anything related to it on internet.
After some practical work about my problem I noticed that this error occurs when the device's passcode is turned on and the device is locked then sqlite don't have permissions to use the sqlite database file because of that this error occurs.